# Copying data where columns are the same but in different order

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that are structurally identical in every aspect except column order, and I need to transfer the data from one to the other.

Normally, I would solve this through e.g. `INSERT INTO tbl1 SELECT * FROM tbl2`, but of course this won't work because the columns are out of order.

I know I can specify the columns manually (`INSERT INTO tbl1 (col1, col2, ..., coln) SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln FROM tbl2`) but I have inherited a project where this scenario happens for more than two hundred tables, and I would very much like to not have to do all that manual labour.

I tried variations of getting the column names through `SELECT COLUMN NAME` in the information_schema, but I couldn't get that to work, which is kinda sensible on MySQL's part anyway. Worst case I could write a script that reads all tables and then all columns for each table, constructing a query that I can run that way. But I'd ideally like a pure MySQL solution, if any exists.

Comment: I think you're going to need dynamic SQL here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks. That does not seem unlikely but is way outside of my knowledge zone.

Comment: It's way outside my knowledge zone as well.  Just a thought: Maybe you could export the table, then reimport using `LOAD DATA` and specify a different column order.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suspect I might still have to specify columns manually, but I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: maybe interesting? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16480/how-can-i-select-using-the-same-fields-from-an-undetermined-number-of-tables-usi

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thanks, @RyanVincent!